# Computer unexpected shutdown in every 5-10 minutes

Tags: windows-7, crash, shutdown

I am using Windows 7, 32-bit operating system. Yesterday, it was working fine. But, today, it is unexpected shutting down in every 5 - 10 minutes. I had tried to google this problem, and tried to reset power plan change, but when I clicked, it shutdown again.

> Can you resolve this problem, please?

I add these picture, that can  help to recognize the problem:

[image]

[image]

> What is `Minidump` given in second picture?

#### Update:

I was [chatting on SO](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36201349#36201349), and after uninstalled VLC, the problem was resolved, VLC was triggering problem.

Comment: is it turning off (which would indicate a hardware or driver issue) or is it using the "normal" shutdown procedure?

Comment: @masgo, it shows blue screen with some text for 2-3 seconds, I think there is some problem!

Comment: Looks like some kind of a hardware problem. Try to run memtest.

Comment: There are so many things this could be. Boot into Safe Mode. This should give you the ability to look around to find the problem.  Disable *automatic restart after system failure* so you can see the details of the blue screen. Here is [how to do that](https://www.lifewire.com/disable-the-automatic-restart-on-system-failure-in-windows-7-2626275). Once you have the details, [edit] your question to include them.

Comment: many bluescreens are caused by either wrong/broken driver or by broken hardware. You can give this tool a try: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html .. it gives some more informations about where the error might come from. then you just have to check your machine systematically ... I recommend a linux live cd

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous What do you do when you "crack on the two"?

Comment: BSODs are often related to driver problems, as pointed out by masgo. Can you show a screenshot of your Windows update history? It should be accessible through Windows Update, but I don't know the exact steps and don't have a Windows 7 machine on hand to check. Also, have you updated any other hardware drivers recently?

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous No, I literally meant to ask you *what do you do when you "crack on the two"?*. You suggested that the OP should "1. crack on the two, enclosure, etc. /.../". Because I have never heard the expression "crack on the two", I asked what you meant by that.

Comment: upload the files from C:\windows\minidump (to onedrive) and post the share link here

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  SU's Q&A model relies on questions being just questions and solutions being in answer posts.  Please consider moving your update to an answer.  Then accepting one of the answers will indicate that the problem has been solved.

Comment: @fixer1234, done. Thanks for nice explabation.

Answer (score 4):

I found this answer here on avast website:
https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=199176.0

What happened?
BSOD on Windows 7 32bit with 170320-0 virus definition update.

How to fix
Fix is going to be included in the 170320-1 virus definition update. Temporary workaround is to disable File System Shield component.

When was it fixed?
Timeline (CEST):
Mar 20 8AM - Virus definition version 170320-0 released
Mar 20 11AM - First mentions on forum about the BSOD
Mar 20 2pm - Release of 170320-1 with the fix started
Mar 20 5pm - (expected) virus definition 170320-1 version released

Thank you!
We're very thankful to our Avast users especially those who posted here on the forum! You helped us discover the root cause much faster which drastically sped up our delivery of the fix.

Have a good day,
Petr
« Last Edit: Today at 04:05:11 PM by petr.chytil »

I applied it on computers of my clients and there isn't issues until now.

Answer (score 1):

I was [chatting on SO](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36201349#36201349), and after uninstalled VLC, the problem was resolved, VLC was triggering problem.

I'd removed Avast Antivirus too.